# Are math definitions iff statements?

Tags: terminology, definition

I was wondering if definitions in mathematics are "if and only" statements?

I know for sure that theorems are not "iff" statements.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, they are. But usually only "if" is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any definition is a 'iff' statement, though we use just 'if' in definition.